# Contentful CMS not extracting correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, database, contentful

Contentful CMS

I am trying to fetch the data and structure it nicely but it is returning it like a massive nested object and things like

```js
{{post.section4Facts.content[1].content[1].content[0].value}}
```

need to happen so I can get the needed value.
I would love to know how to organize it and if there is any resource that I can get since the contentful CMS website don't have an answer to my question.

````js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ServiceService } from '../service.service';
import * as contentful from 'contentful';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-details',
  templateUrl: './post-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-details.component.scss']
})
export class PostDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  postId: any;
  post: any;
  tags: any[] = [];
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private apiService: ServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.postId = params['id'];
      console.log(this.postId);

      const client = contentful.createClient({
        space: '****',
        accessToken: '****',
      });

      client.getEntry(this.postId).then(entry => {
        this.post = entry.fields;
        
        this.tags = entry.metadata.tags
        console.log(this.tags[0].sys.id);
        
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    });
  }
}


>! and this is the template code:


<div class="container" *ngIf="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <article class="article-post">
                <div class="article-header">
                    <h1 class="article-title" *ngIf="post.title">{{post.title}}</h1>
                    <img class="article-img" src={{post.image?.fields.file.url}} alt="">
                    <div class="article-meta">
                        <span class="meta-date"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> May 20, 2023</span>
                        <span class="meta-category " *ngFor="let tag of tags"> <i class="far fa-folder"></i> {{tag?
                            tag.sys.id : 'No tags'}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="article-content">
                    <h2>{{post.section1Title}}</h2>
                    <p>{{post.description.content[0].content[0].value}}</p>
                    <!-- section 1 explained desc -->
                    <p>{{post.section1Info.content[0].content[0].value}}</p>
                    <!-- section 2 my thoughts -->

                    <h2>{{post.section2Title}}</h2>
                    <p>{{post.section2Experience.content[0].content[0].value}}</p>
                    <!-- section 3 info -->

                    <h2>{{post.section3Title}}</h2>
                    <p>{{post.section3UseCase.content[0].content[0].value}}</p>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p>{{post.blockquote1.content[0].content[0].value}}</p>
                    </blockquote>
                    <p><sub>{{post.section4Title}}</sub></p>
                    <p>{{post.section4Facts.content[0].content[0].value}}</p>
                    <a href="{{post.section4Facts.content[1].content[1].content[0].value}}">MDN library</a>

                    <!-- <ul *ngIf="post.table !== undefined">
                        <li *ngFor="let li of post.table.content[0].content[1].content">
                            {{li.content[0].content[0].data.value}}</li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul> -->
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <aside class="sidebar">
                <div class="widget">
                    <h5 class="widget-title">About Me</h5>
                    <div class="widget-content">
                        <a href="/about">Hello there! My name is Boyan, and I'm delighted to welcome you to my online
                            development blog.</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="widget">
                    <h5 class="widget-title">Categories</h5>
                    <div class="widget-content">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Miscellaneous</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="widget">
                    <h5 class="widget-title">Tags</h5>
                    <div class="widget-content">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled tag-cloud">
                            <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>```
````

Comment: Hey, what is the field type you are using for Post? Is it Rich Text or something else?

Comment: Setup a helper to hydrate the data into local Type(s). Then w/the clean structured data; do whatever you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at your models and see if they can be restructured. If not or it wouldn't be of any help then you may have to do it the long way. Write up something to hydrate your local Models (object/type/interface/etc…) from the incoming nested mess. Then you'll have nice objects locally to work with and/or persist to storage.